# transfer each row of a matrix to the field of a structure

Tags: matlab, structure, vectorization

I have a 100 by 2 matrix. I want to transfer each row of this matrix to the field of a structure without using loop. For loop solution:

```
% Let's say
matrix = rand(100,2);
for ii = 1: size(matrix,1)
    str(ii).field = matrix(ii,:);
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can improve this question by telling us what you've tried, and possibly why the loop solution is not practical for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [comma-separated](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) nature of both struct arrays and cell arrays:

```
nRow   = 100;
nCol   = 2;
matrix = rand(nRow,2);

% Chunk the matrix into a 100x1 cell array of 1x2 entries
matrixCell = mat2cell(matrix,ones(1,nRow),nCol);

% Pre-allocate and splay the entries into the struct array
str(nRow).field = [];
[str(:).field]  = matrixCell{:};
```

---

Per Divakar's comment below, you can also use the [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) function itself to create the array directly:

```
str = struct('field',matrixCell);
```

---

Just a note a efficiency (in terms of run-time), pre-allocation of a struct array and then populating it with a loop is the fastest solution:

```
str(nRow).field = [];
for k = 1:nRow
    str(k).field = matrix(k,:);
end
```

This approach is nearly 10 times as fast as the first two, mainly due to the computational overhead of creating the cell array (`mat2cell`).

Comment: Do you really have to pre-allocate? How about `str = struct('field',mat2cell(matrix,ones(m,1),n))`, where `[m,n] =  size(matrix)`?

Comment: @Divakar That works too.  I use literals so often I forget about the functions that can be used to create the data structure.  Personal style problem I guess.

Comment: @Divakar I clarified the code by explicitly naming the cell array `matrixCell` (my original intent).